# Passing JS array to PHP for a Contact Form from scratch

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm creating my own contact form from scratch. Currently I'm trying to make the JS universal so when I make another form on my website it will use the same code.

I want to get input whether if I'm doing it right or wrong, and need help with with passing an array to PHP that will pass in the array what elements have the attributes `required`(true or false).

Currently my JS array consist of:

```
var inputData = ({name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).val(), required: $(this).attr('required')});
```

`inputData` is the array I pass to php which in the php goes through and verify that all of the information that user inputted is all correct. Which it checks if the input is `required` because not all inputs are required.

So in my PHP I have a simple array that gets the posted data from my JS code.

```
$emailData= array(array('f_name' => $_POST['f_name']),
            array('l_name' => $_POST['l_name']),
            array('p_num' => $_POST['p_num']),
            array('contact_email' => $_POST['contact_email']),
            array('message' => $_POST['message']),
            array('botCheck' => $_POST['botCheck']));
```

I though only get value and I know why that is. But I'm unsure how to basically direct the php array to grab `required` from the corresponding value.

I know that someone can simply remove the required attr in the html but my initial thought is to but the form in database so that the php knows what really is required in case someone tries to remove the required attribute. Is that the way to do it or is it much more simpler?

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint it's not recommend so send information about if a field is recommended or not from the client. This should ideally be configured on the server side. You could configure a PHP array and output the fields on the HTML by looping through the PHP array:

```
// Render
$fields = [
    "f_name" => [
        "required" => true
    ],
    "l_name" => [
        "required" => true
    ],
    "message" => [
        "required" => false
    ],
    // ... configure all your fields here
];

foreach ($fields as $name => $config) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='$name'>";
}
```

Then in the script that receives the data:

```
// Post - check required fields
foreach ($fields as $name => $config) {
    if (empty($_POST[$name]) && $config["required"]) {
        die("Error! Field $name is mandatory!");
    }
}
```

Comment: can this still be done if I have a contact.php and I'm sending the info to a email.php script?

Comment: So sense I'm passing values through js so that the page doesn't reload. Would it be wise to make a json file make the php that the person sees use the `contact` form values from json then in the sendmail script have it reference the json to find out what is required?